# Multilevel relative import

Tags: python, relative-path, python-packaging

Multilevel relative import

I have following folder structure

```
top\
   __init__.py
   util\
      __init__.py
      utiltest.py
   foo\
      __init__.py
      foo.py
      bar\
         __init__.py
         foobar.py
```

I want to access from `foobar.py` the module `utiltest.py`. I tried following relative import, but this doesn't work:
`from ...util.utiltest import *`

I always get 
`ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

How to do such a multileve relative import?

Comment: why relative import ? an absolute import should be the easiest way of doing this ;) : `from util.utiltest import *`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must import `foobar` from the parent folder of `top`:

```
import top.foo.bar.foobar
```

This tells Python that `top` is the top level package. Relative imports are possible only inside a package.

Answer (score 14):

I realize this is an old question, but I feel the accepted answer likely misses the main issue with the questioner's code. It's not wrong, strictly speaking, but it gives a suggestion that only coincidentally happens to work around the real issue.

That real issue is that the `foobar.py` file in `top\foo\bar` is being run as a script. When a (correct!) relative import is attempted, it fails because the Python interpreter doesn't understand the package structure.

The best fix for this is to run `foobar.py` not by filename, but instead to use the `-m` flag to the interpreter to tell it to run the `top.foo.bar.foobar` module. This way Python will know the main module it's loading is in a package, and it will know exactly where the relative import is referring.