# Python3 -m run configuration in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, python-import

**Update 2021**: *Solution is built into PyDev/Eclipse*

See accepted answer for details

**Original Question (and old answers) for below**

As many comments/questions/rants on SO and other places will tell you, Python3 packages using relative imports want to be run from a central `__main__.py` file. In the case where a module, say "modA" within a package, say "packA", that uses relative imports needs to be run (for instance because a test package is run `if __name__ == '__main__'`), we are told to run instead run `python3 -m modA.packA` from the directory above `modA` if `sys.path()` does not contain the directory above `modA`.  I may dislike this paradigm, but I can work around it.

When trying to run `modA` from Eclipse/PyDev, however, I can't figure out how to specify a run configuration that will execute the module properly with the `-m` flag.  Has anyone figured out how to set up a run configuration that will do this properly?

References: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) ; [Relative import in Python 3 is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637428/relative-import-in-python-3-not-working) ; [Multilevel relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277200/multilevel-relative-import?rq=1)

Comment: PyDev always give me headaches when including your source folder in the PYTHONPATH section of the options. Are you including any of your module/folders there? (it isn't that you should or not, but just to have a bit of background to replicate your case)

Comment: I have some projects which set the PYTHONPATH and some where it doesn't. I don't think it's a major difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays (since **PyDev 5.4.0 (2016-11-28)**) you can go to the `Settings > PyDev > Run` and select `Launch modules with python -m mod.name` instead of `python filename.py` ;)

See: https://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html

---

For older versions of PyDev (old answer)

Unfortunately, right now, it's not automatic running with `-m` in PyDev, so, I'll present 3 choices to work in PyDev with relative imports which are preceded by a `dot` (in PyDev version 4.3.0):

1. Don't use relative imports, only absolute imports in your `__main__` modules.
2. Create a separate module for the `__main__` which will do an absolute import for the module you want to run and run that module instead (if you're distributing your application, this is probably needed anyways as the usual way for people to launch your code in Python is by passing the script as an argument to Python and not using the `-m` switch).
3. Add the `-m module` to the vm arguments in your run configuration by doing:

- Make the run (which will fail because of the relative import)
- Right-click the editor > Copy Context Qualified Name
- Open the run configuration: Alt, R, N (i.e.: Toolbar > Run > Run Configuration)
- Open arguments tab and add the '-m Ctrl+V' (to add the -m and the module name you copied previously).

Although this is definitely not ideal: you'll now receive an argument with the filename (as PyDev will always pass that to run the file) and the whole process is a nuisance.

As a note, I do hope to provide a way to make runs within PyDev using the `-m` soon (**hopefully for PyDev 4.4.0**)... although this may not be possible if the file being run is not under the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: to run an external file it still has to support the option without the `-m`).

Comment: Thank you Fabio for this reply (and the amazing work on PyDev).  I had been using solution #1 forever, but I was beginning to feel that the inheritance structure would be much easier to understand/more robust against multiple installations if I could use relative imports. #2 had the problem that I'd lose the "Run" ability on a given module from PyDev. #3 is the most promising -- I'll set it as a separate answer here to show what I did; maybe it could get into PyDev 4.4. :-)

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, Fabio!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit nasty trick possible here to work around this issue. I'm using PyDev 9.2.0

Put your venv right in the workspace, say  under the dir "venv".

Refresh your eclipse workspace and ensure that it uses this venv (through your interpreter setup).

After the refresh, go to the run configuration and edit the "Main Module" by clicking the Browse button.
The venv will now appear.

Browse into the venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages

There you will find the pip-installed module source codes and you can select the module you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021**: *This answer is no longer needed.  See accepted answer for details.*

Here's what I was able to do after Fabio's great suggestion.

Create a program called `/usr/local/bin/runPy3M` with world read/execute permissions, with the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3 -u
'''
Run submodules inside packages (with relative imports) given
a base path and a path (relative or absolute) to the submodule
inside the package.

Either specify the package root with -b, or setenv ECLIPSE_PROJECT_LOC.
'''

import argparse
import os
import re
import subprocess
import sys

def baseAndFileToModule(basePath, pyFile):
    '''
    Takes a base path referring to the root of a package
    and a (relative or absolute) path to a python submodule
    and returns a string of a module name to be called with
    python -m MODULE, if the current working directory is
    changed to basePath.

    Here the CWD is '/Users/cuthbert/git/t/server/tornadoHandlers/'.

    >>> baseAndFileToModule('/Users/cuthbert/git/t/', 'bankHandler.py')
    'server.tornadoHandlers.bankHandler'
    '''
    absPyFilePath = os.path.abspath(pyFile)
    absBasePath = None
    if basePath is not None:
        absBasePath = os.path.abspath(basePath)
        commonPrefix = os.path.commonprefix([absBasePath, absPyFilePath])
        uncommonPyFile = absPyFilePath[len(commonPrefix):]
    else:
        commonPrefix = ""
        uncommonPyFile = absPyFilePath 

    if commonPrefix not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(commonPrefix)

    moduleize = uncommonPyFile.replace(os.path.sep, ".")
    moduleize = re.sub("\.py.?$", "", moduleize)
    moduleize = re.sub("^\.", "", moduleize)
    return moduleize    

def exitIfPyDevSetup():
    '''
    If PyDev is trying to see if this program is a valid
    Python Interpreter, it expects to function just like Python.
    This is a little module that does this if the last argument
    is 'interpreterInfo.py' and then exits.
    '''
    if 'interpreterInfo.py' in sys.argv[-1]:
        interarg = " ".join([sys.executable] + sys.argv[1:])
        subprocess.call(interarg.split())
        exit()
    return

exitIfPyDevSetup()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run a python file or files as a module.')
parser.add_argument('file', metavar='pyfile', type=str, nargs=1,
                   help='filename to run, with .py')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--basepath', type=str, default=None, metavar='path',
                   help='path to directory to consider the root above the package')
parser.add_argument('-u', action='store_true', help='unbuffered binary stdout and stderr (assumed)')
args = parser.parse_args()
pyFile = args.file[0]
basePath = args.basepath

if basePath is None and 'ECLIPSE_PROJECT_LOC' in os.environ:
    basePath = os.environ['ECLIPSE_PROJECT_LOC']

modName = baseAndFileToModule(basePath, pyFile)

allPath = ""
if basePath:
   allPath += "cd '" + basePath + "'; "

allPath += sys.executable
allPath += " -m " + modName 

subprocess.call(allPath, shell=True)  # maybe possible with runpy instead...
```

Then add a new interpreter to PyDev -- call it what you'd like (e.g., `runPy3M`) and point the interpreter to `/usr/local/bin/runPy3M`.  Click okay.  Then move it up the list if need be.  Then add to environment for the interpreter, Variable: `ECLIPSE_PROJECT_LOC` (name here DOES matter) with value `${project_loc}`.

Now submodules inside packages that choose this interpreter will run as modules relative to the sub package.

I'd like to see `baseAndFileToModule(basePath, pyFile)` added to `runpy` eventually as another run option, but this will work for now.

EDIT: Unfortunately, after setting all this up, it appears that this configuration seems to prevent Eclipse/PyDev from recognizing builtins such as "None", "True", "False", "isinstnance," etc.  So not a perfect solution.

Comment: As a note, as you noted, yes, you can add any script to run as Python (even a Python wrapper) -- so, the issue you're having with the builtins is mostly related to that (it's not a real python wrapper... if you do a pure shell script that executes Python passing the args it should work though).

Comment: As a note, as it seems you're up to digg to fix this, you could try fixing PyDev itself... take a look at org.python.pydev.debug.ui.launching.PythonRunnerConfig.getCommandLine(boolean) -- and see http://www.pydev.org/developers.html on how to get/setup the environment for coding.

Comment: Oh! Duh! The beauty of open source. Yes I'll try it and submit a patch/pull request etc. :-)

Comment: (Unfortunately, I never got around to doing that)

Comment: This question/answer is quite old.. nowadays you can go to the `Settings > PyDev > Run ` and select `Launch modules with python -m mod.name` instead of `python filename.py` ;)

Comment: THANKS!  Will edit the Q to reference that!