# PyCharm not recognizing Django project imports: from my_app.models import thing

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-import

I just started testing out PyCharm on my existing Django project, and it doesn't recognize any imports from apps within my project:

in `my_app1/models.py`:

`from my_app2.models import thing`

"Unresolved reference 'my_app2'"

Why is this? My project's directory structure matches the [recommended layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/#your-project-and-your-reusable-app), and it runs without errors, it's just PyCharm's magic doesn't want to work on it.

It seems related to this question:
[Import app in django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583687/import-app-in-django-project)

But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  If I try:

`from ..my_app2.models import thing`

The PyCharm error goes away and it can auto predict, etc. But when I run the project Django throws:

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

EDIT:

Project structure:

```
my_project/
   src/
      manage.py
      db.sqlite3
      my_app1/
         templates/
         __init.py__
         admin.py
         models.py
         urls.py
         views.py
         ...
      my_app2/
         templates/
         __init.py__
         admin.py
         models.py
         urls.py
         views.py
         ...
      my_project_app/
         settings/
         __init.py__
         urls.py
         ...
```

Comment: Have you tried: from .models import thing?

Comment: I want to import from a different app in my project than the one I am in.  So this will just get my current app's models

Comment: Its resolving it correctly because you don't have a `my_app` module below the file where you are writing that code.

Comment: Can you please edit this question adding your project's directory structure? and explain from which file you want to import which

Comment: clarification added. Thanks!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I was having this issue using a "2 Scoops of Django" project layout, e.g.

```
/project_root
    /project_dir
        /config
            /settings
        /my_app
            /tests
            models.py
    /requirements
    readme.rst
```

The code was working, but in /tests, IntelliJ/PyCharm showed an unresolved reference:

```
from my_app.models import Something
```

I had all the `__init__.py` files in place. I ended up having to set the sources root to `project_dir`:

Right-click on project_dir, Mark Directory as > Sources Root

Comment: My personal hero. This was nagging me for quite some time!

Comment: Thank you. Everything worked well and then this issue appeared. Marking as Sources Root resolved the problem

Comment: Thanks! This issuer was bugging me for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I can take a look over you project structure I can tell you that the problem appears to be related to a missing `__init__.py` in your 'src' folder. Try adding an empty file named `__init__.py` in the root of 'src' folder.

Also, take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277200/multilevel-relative-import), I think is the same problem or a very similar one.

Hope this could be useful, cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I was having this issue after I change my environment to virtualenv, so I changed my python interpreter to my current virtualenv.

Go to File > Settings > Project Interpreter.
In that window you would be able to see all packages includes on this interpreter, Django should be there.

This worked for me.

Link about: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206598665-Unresolved-Reference-Errors-for-django

Comment: It's about django. Not about project modules. I.e. constructions like `from django.conf import settings` will work, and constructions like `from my_app.models import Model` will not work.