# Intellij not able to detect syntax of static assets loaded in django project

Tags: python, html, django, intellij-idea

#### Setting up virtual environment

```sh
$ pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
$ mkdir Django; cd Django;
$ virtualenv django-virtual-env -p python3
$ ls django-virtual-env 
bin        lib        pyvenv.cfg
$ source django-virtual-env/bin/activate
(django-virtual-env) $ 
(django-virtual-env) $ which python3
$PWD/env_blog/bin/python3
(django-virtual-env) $ deactivate
$
```

#### pip dependencies required

```sh
pip install django
```

#### Setting up intellij for your project

- Configure Python interpreter

  - File -> Project Structure -> SDKs -> + -> Add Python SDK -> Virtual Environment -> Existing Environment
    -> (Set the interpretter to absolute path) ./django-virtual-env/bin/python
- Configure the project to be able to import the python modules

  - [Right-click on project_dir -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342618/pycharm-not-recognizing-django-project-imports-from-my-app-models-import-thing)

### Still the following syntax is not getting detected. The code is correct and working. Not sure what is the issue

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Django project configuration in IDEA is quite cumbersome, please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34155 The ticket has a screencast demonstrating the setup.

I believe the easiest way is:

- Lets assume we have a directory `A` which is a Django project root
- Open `A` in IDEA
- Open **File | Project Structure**
- Open **Project Settings | Modules**
- Remove the existing module if doesn't have Django facet under it right away
- Click `+` and **Import Module** -> Select `A`
- Create module from existing sources
- Once done - select Django facet and populate it's settings